# Entity Framework error during unit test

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework.

In one of my unit tests I have a line like:

```
this.Set<T>().Add(entity);
```

On executing that line I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The model backing the
>   'InvoiceNewDataContext' context has changed since the database was
>   created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call
>   Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For
>   example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will
>   automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it
>   with new data.

Well I've actually deleted the database and removed the connection string.

I'm surprised this error is happening on adding as I wouldn't expect it to happen until I saved the data and it discovered there was no database.

In previous projects/solutions I created during unit tests I have been able to add to the context for test purposes without actually calling `SaveChanges`.

Would anyone know why this would be happening in my latest projects/solutions?

Comment: Are you using an Initialization strategy in application start or in test Initializer method ? And what do you mean by `removed the coonnectionstring`?

Comment: Yes I was using an initialization strategy and I had a connectionstring in the app.config of the test project. I wanted the tests to run without the database so I removed this connectionstring and commented out the initialization strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it really didn't use database in your previous projects? If you do not specify any connection string it will silently use a default one to SQLExpress database with local .mdf file so make sure that isn't happening now.

Comment: Well at the moment I'm comparing it to the example found at http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-design-a-unit-testable-domain-model-with-entity-framework-code-first/ This doesn't seem to have an associated database and you can add items to the context like: context.Save(product);
                context.SaveChanges(); when you're testing.